# Custom equation environment using cleveref gives wrong numbering

Tags: equations, environments, counters, cleveref, equation-number

I want to make a custom environment for important equation and use separate numbering for these. I got it working as shown in my *"MWE"*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=black,
    }  % Hyper referations
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref} % nosort here solves my problem, but that also removes the to thing which is very nice

\newcounter{ieqcounter}
\newenvironment{iequation}
    {
    \refstepcounter{ieqcounter}
    \begin{equation} 
    }
    {
    \tag{i.\theieqcounter}
    \end{equation} 
    }

%% I guess something here should fix it?
    
\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
    1 = 1 \label{eq:1}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        2=2 \label{eq:2}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
       3=3 \label{eq:3}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        4=4 \label{eq:4}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        5 = 5 \label{eq:5}
    \end{equation}
                
    \cref{eq:1,eq:3,eq:5}

 \begin{iequation}
    1+i = 1+i \label{eq:i1}
    \end{iequation}
    \begin{iequation}
        2+i=2+i \label{eq:i2}
    \end{iequation}
    \begin{equation}
        2+2=4 \label{thisIsStandardEquation}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{iequation}
       3+i=3+i \label{eq:i3}
    \end{iequation}
    \begin{iequation}
        4+i=4+i \label{eq:i4}
    \end{iequation}
   \begin{iequation}
        5+i=5+i \label{eq:i5}
    \end{iequation}             
    \cref{eq:i1,eq:i3,eq:i5}\par
    This should be (i.1),(i.3) and (i.5)
\end{document}
```

I get the right output, in terms of numbering on the equations (for now i.equation number for important equations) and normal equation numbers for all other equations.

[image]

But when I use cref to refer to the special equations it gives me wrong output. I just says first equation to last equation. So how can I fix this, so it shows me it correctly (i.1), (i.3) and (i.5)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can disable it in this one instance with `\cref{eq:i1,,eq:i3,,eq:i5}` (two commas between the entries). If you want to disable compression globally. use the `sort` package option instead of the (implicit) default `sort&compress`.

Comment: @frabjous this works, but it also removes the to, in for example (i.1) to (i.3) if I were to reference (i.1) , (i.2) and (i.3)

Comment: In that case I'd use the double commas to disable it on a case by case basis. Maybe it's not perfect, but I don't know an alternative. Someone else might.